# Unable to create cookie which isn't httponly in Laravel Cookie::queue

Tags: javascript, laravel, cookies, laravel-5.1

I want to create a cookie with `httpOnly = false`, This is what I am doing now

`Cookie::queue("key", "val", 30, null, null, false, false);`

but I can't access that cookie in `javascript`, also I noted that `http flag` is set in the developer tools for that cookie.

Did I miss something?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the Laravel version flag is correct, it's better practice to use Dependency Injection on your controller method:

```
public function controllerAction(\Illuminate\Cookie\CookieJar $cookieJar)
{
    $cookieJar->queue(cookie("key", "val", 30, null, null, false, false));
    return response()->view('Somedir.viewname');
    // Or any other type of response you'd want to return
}
```

More information: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-to-set-a-cookie-with-laravel-5

Typically, Laravel HTTPKernel Cookies are encrypted and are only decryptable by your application.

If you want to access the value of a cookie using Javascript, use a conditional statement in your view that can access the decrypted value of the cookie:

```
// someview.blade.php
@if ( request()->cookie('nameOfCookie') )
    <script>
        var cookieValue = '{!! request()->cookie('nameOfCookie') !!}';
    </script>
@endif
```

This way you will only see the value if it has been set on the request. You can test for the cookie value being set outside of the code above quite simply:

```
<script>
    if (cookieValue)
    {
        // Do something!
    }
<script>
```

Remember to change the output type if you're not storing a string. An array to string conversion will be necessary using a function like `implode(string $glue, array $array)` http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php